# Attach an image gallery carousel to nodes

Tags: 7, entities, media

I want to attach an image gallery to a node, showing the images in a carousel view so that only a few thumbnails are shown and clicking on them opens a ColorBox overlay.

I have a gallery content type that contains all images in a field, and in an article the gallery is referenced using an entity reference field.

I found the [Gallery Formatter](http://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter) module which does nearly want I want. But I don't want to display the large image on the page, only the carousel showing thumbnails. To get the full size image one should click on one of the thumbnails.

So I need a field formatter that can display the contents of an image field as a carousel. Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Adding a jQuery Image Carousel to your Node View](http://ericlondon.com/posts/184-adding-a-jquery-image-carousel-to-your-node-view).

Though the above article is for Drupal 6, you can follow this like below:

- As the gallery is referenced in the "Article" content type, you can modify the template file for that content type, and fetch the gallery images.
- After that, you can display that in carousel.

The other way is using a theme preprocess function.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Your code.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently, the best solution i think is to  use this module [Field Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow). Read about it, what you need is to install this module, then u need to create two image styles for thumbnails and for image. In your content type in **Manage Display** settings u can configure your carousel. Also u need to install this modules

```
Libraries API,
Jquery Cycle plugin, JCarousel
```

you can read about this module [here](http://drupal.org/project/field_slideshow)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with the [Lightbox2](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) module. Check out the [Grouped images](http://stellapower.net/lightbox2) example.